# jQuery AJAX data parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, parameters, unify

I have 10 AJAX queries with the same parameters.

```
$.ajax({
    global: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: value,
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
        firstname: $("#firstname").val(),
        lastname: $("#lastname").val(),
        surname: $("#surname").val(),
        age: $("#age").val(),
        ...
        sex: $("#sex").val()
    },
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        serviceError();
    }
});
```

How I can unify these parameters not to write them 10 times because I have 76 parameters?

Comment: You can do it before your ajax call.

Comment: @IsraGab okay, but how. Can you show me?

Comment: You want to pass all fields within a form, you can use 
`data: $('#form').serialize();`
If not, you can prepare a string with all parameters in the form of 
`data : $('#form').serialize() + "&par1=1&par2=2&par3=232"` 
just loop through the available params and preare a string

Comment: How looks your html code of your params?

Comment: The field names are all very uniform so you could easily use a one-line loop to add all 76 properties to an object before the $.ajax() call.

Comment: @nnnnnn for example I gave them numbers, they have different names.

Comment: @jeetaz I update my code, did you think your idea will do that I want ?

Comment: @diank better to post entire html if the answer provided in the post by XtraSimplicity don't work for you. Yes, to your question.

Comment: `$(this).serialize()` if you're using `$('form').submit(function(){...});`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, create a single class for each of your `param` in your html
something like:

```
<input type="text" id="param1" class="params"/>
<input type="text" id="param2" class="params"/>
<input type="text" id="param3" class="params"/>
```

Then in your JS:

```
 var callAjax = function(){    
    data = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < $('.params').length; i++){
        data[$('.params')[i].id] = $('.params')[i].val(); 
    }
    $.ajax({
            global: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: value,
            dataType: 'html',
            data: data,
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                serviceError();
            }
        });
        }
```

Comment: for example I gave them numbers, they have different names.

Comment: okay I edit my code too. I don't think your code will do that I want.

Comment: So I don't know what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Add your value in array variable then pass to data